# Java servlets :HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL while accessing JSP pages

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have one login.html , LoginServlet and home.jsp. But while redirecting to home.jsp ,I get HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL. When i try directing to html page , it works fine. Problem is only in directing the jsp pages .Please advice .

login.html

```
<form action="./LoginServlet" method="post">
<div class ="login">

  <label><b>User Name</b></label>
  <input type="text"name="name"placeholder="UserName" onclick=""required><br/>

  <label><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

  <button type="submit">Login</button>

  <input type="checkbox"checked="checked">Remember me
</div>
</form>
```

Below is my LoginServlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginServlet() {


    }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Initial setting

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    //Gather data
    String name= request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    try {
        boolean status =LoginDao.validateUser(name, password);
        if(status){


            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("name", name);
            //response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
             RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");  
             rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        else{
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<body>");
             out.println("<h1>Sorry username or password error</h1>");  
             RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");  
             rd.include(request,response);
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</head>");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Below is home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome To UTS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<header><b>Welcome to UTS</b></header>
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="linux.jsp">Linux</a></li>
    <li><a href="risc.jsp">Risc</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>UTS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fidelity.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SignupServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SignupServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fidelity.SignupServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignupServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SignupServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Where did you map the URL ? web.xml or @Webservlet ? Can you add the code for it ?

Comment: @javaguy i have added the web.xml file.

Comment: I tried your the core of code. it works. It's everything republished, synchronized, deployed? Are you sure you forward to the right file? You can try change the login.html to use get? Is then the forward working? Do you have any other redirects (in not shown code), before the if(status) block? Try just the line in your doPost: request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: @code_angel I have tried but it does not work. If i tried creating other testapp and getting same issues .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

You can use

```
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
return;
```

in your LoginServlet if(status) block.

EDIT:

[RequestDispatcher.forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-)s only the request and response objects.
The session and context are independent accessible.

In the Servlet the session attribute "name" has been set, so it is available in any other following requests. Until the session expires, the session cookie is deleted or the attribute is removed.

In the JSP you can use: `${sessionScope.name}` to display it.

The [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is managed by the servlet container.
If problems with Session occur, you can check:

- if the session cookie JSESSIONID is set,
- if JSESSIONID is the same in following requests.

Comment: sendRedirect will not keep seession attributes .